# How to show a specific view from a table in MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm new to database concepts. So, i need some help in solving a particular problem.
Say i have a table named emp whose data are as below:

```
id | dept | doj
100 | FS | 02-04-13
100 | HST | 02-04-14
100 | ETA | 02-04-15
```

What i want to display is:

```
id | from | to | doj
100 | FS | HST | 02-04-14
100 | HST | ETA | 02-04-15
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
The database i'm using is MS-SQL server 13v.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and the likelihood that someone can help you.  In particular, it is easier if you post what you have tried so far and others can offer specific instructions on how to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.id, t.dept as [from], t1.dept as [to], t1.doj 
from table t cross apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table t1
      where t1.id = t.id and t1.doj > t.doj
      order by t1.doj
     ) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to get data from current and subsequent row in the same result set, you may use [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    id int,
    dept varchar(10),
    doj date
)
INSERT INTO #Table 
    (id, dept, doj)
VALUES
    (100, 'FS',  '2013-04-02'),
    (100, 'HST', '2014-04-02'),
    (100, 'ETA', '2015-04-02'),
    (101, 'XTA', '2015-04-02'),
    (101, 'YTA', '2015-04-02')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        id,
        dept [from],
        LEAD(dept) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, doj) AS [to],
        LEAD(doj) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, doj)  AS [doj]
    FROM #Table
    ) t
WHERE t.[to] IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
id  from    to  doj
100 FS      HST 2014-04-02
100 HST     ETA 2015-04-02
101 XTA     YTA 2015-04-02
```

Answer (score 0):

With a self join to the table:

```
select t.id, tt.dept [from], t.dept [to], t.doj
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.id = t.id and
tt.doj = (select max(doj) from tablename where id = t.id and doj < t.doj)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=777da85befd24b351ade364748b0bbf0)